# Model return empty array when use select in model (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8, eloquent-relationship

I have a **hasOne(Many)** relation function like this:

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Models\ProductTranslation','product_id','id')->where('language_id', $language_id['id']);
```

Also, I tried to use

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Models\ProductTranslation','product_id','id')->select('product_translations.name')->where('language_id', '1');
```

In Controller use this

```
$value=Product::with('translation:name')->find(1);
```

I try to receive only one specific column from the table, but it returned an empty array. In debug bar I see the query when I use it in PHPMyAdmin it return only one column as I want.

Is this possible?

P.S (use Laravel 5.8.34)

**Updating**

I choose 'Entity Layers for Translated Fields and Non-Translated Fields' approach for translation in the project and have a database like this [Database picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btWa5.jpg)

Comment: `select()` must always contains the foreign key column.

Comment: Resolve by you comment @TharakaDilshan 
`$value=Product::with('translation:name,**product_id**')->find(1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get only that **language_id** type of **translation** then you might do like this.

```
$language_id = 1;
$products = Product::with(array('translation'=>function($query) use($language_id){
    $query->where('language_id',$language_id);
}))->get();
```

and if you want to select name then like this
make sure you've to select **id,name**  `id` is a must.

```
$language_id = 1;
$products = Product::with(array('translation'=>function($query) use($language_id){
    $query->where('language_id',$language_id)->select('id','name');
}))->get();
```

Remove where conditions from models.

As per your DB structure in **Language** it's belongsToMany with role

**Languages.php model**

```
public function role(){
    returh $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Role','role_translations','language_id','role_id')
}

$language_id = 1;
$products = Product::with(array('translation.role'=>function($query) use($language_id){
    $query->where('role_translations.language_id',$language_id)->select('languages.id','languages.name');
}))->get();
```

Comment: this solution don;t work for me 
Model
`return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductTranslation','product_id','id');`

Controller
`$language_id = 1;
 $products = Product::with(array('translation'=>function($query) use($language_id){
            $query->where('language_id',$language_id)->select('id','name');
        }))->get();`

I choose 'Entity Layers for Translated Fields and Non-Translated Fields' for translation in the project and have a database like this [Database picture](https://imgur.com/a/OClUozi)

Comment: Yeah by comment understand that in select must be a foreign key column

Comment: Have you got your solution?

Comment: Yeah, your answer very good, in future think what I will use.